# Get Road name from coordinates to be used in Overpass api

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have following Overpass api quer that takes the name of the road and give back entire road coordinates

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];(node["name"="%@"];way["name"="%@"];relation["name"="%@"];);(node["ref"="%@"];way["ref"="%@"];relation["ref"="%@"];);out body;>;out skel qt;
```

I am using following query to get the name of road from coordinates

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=%f&lon=%f&zoom=18&addressdetails=1


 NSDictionary *dict = [response JSONValue];
 //NSString *placeId = [dict objectForKey:@"place_id"];
 //NSString *osmId   = [dict objectForKey:@"osm_id"];

 NSDictionary *roadDict = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];
 NSString *roadName = [roadDict objectForKey:@"road"];
```

Currently i have an example of `Roadname @"John F Foran Freeway"` using coordinates

```
[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.731267 longitude:-122.423580];
```

When i use this roadname in my overpass api. I get no results. Why its not detecting the road? Sometimes on few roadnames it work but mostly it don't recognize the road name. What is wrong?

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];(node["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];way["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];relation["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];);(node["ref"="John F Foran Freeway"];way["ref"="John F Foran Freeway"];relation["ref"="John F Foran Freeway"];);out body;>;out skel qt;
```

Comment: Can you provide an URL with the exact query that fails?

Comment: @scai just replace %@ with John F Foran Freeway. It doesn't give any error, it just return empty set. the query is fine. The road names just don't match. Sometimes they do match but are quite rare. I am not sure where Overpass api is getting names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell us how *name* and *ref* are related in your query but in case you want to get all objects with a specific name *AND* ref value then try this query:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  node
    ["name"="John F Foran Freeway"]
    ["ref"="I 280"];
  way
    ["name"="John F Foran Freeway"]
    ["ref"="I 280"];
  relation
    ["name"="John F Foran Freeway"]
    ["ref"="I 280"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can [view the result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/7B7).

If you want to get all roads with a specific name *OR* ref value then use this query instead:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  node["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
  way["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
  relation["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
  node["ref"="I 280"];
  way["ref"="I 280"];
  relation["ref"="I 280"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can [view the result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/7Ba).

But it seems like your reverse geocoding step is unnecessary if you just want to retrieve roads in your current location. Instead of specifying the name of the road just query for all ways with the highway tag in a given bounding box:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  way
    ["highway"]
    (37.79396544487583,-122.3838801383972,37.80200543920775,-122.37458467483522);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Again, you can [view the result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/7Bh).

See the [Overpass API language guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) for more information.

Comment: you didn't get my point. Yes the query is fine. However u have added Ref, Using my reverse geo coding i can only get Road name. THere is no I 280 anywhere using openstreet geocoding

Comment: No I didn't add *ref*, it is already present in the query from your question. You have to tell us the exact query that is failing for your if the query in your question is not the one you are talking about.

Comment: ok, let me paste it out

Comment: i see i am passing in Ref same values as name.

Comment: please check the edits

Comment: That's most probably wrong ;)

Comment: so whats the way to get ref along with road name. road name i get by openstreet map using reverse coding

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you actually want to query. All roads with *both* the given name and ref or all roads with the given name *or* ref?

Comment: Actually i want to get the road i am on USING my geo location. Easiest way in overpass api to me is to get road name and search the api for road name.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question about your ref tag. Anyway, I extended my answer a little bit. Still, if you want to get the road of your current location then you don't need reverse geocoding. Just query for all highways at your current position.

Comment: actually i guess i have no way of finding out the ref since reverse coding api doesn't provide reference. So i am trying without ref with only name

Comment: I still don't see a reason for your geocoding step. Overpass API allows to query for roads by just providing a location.

Comment: i have searched a lot , if u have that solution please share. that would be MOST grateful. Remember i have my current geo location only

Comment: Please see my updated answer.